# What should I do with the "java.lang.AssertionError" error on my Android Studio activity due to a null object response of my website API (Retrofit)?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am having a problem with the API that I have implemented to my website that is connected to an activity in the Android application that I am developing. According to the Logcat of my Android Studio,
that line 118 of the `ForgotPassword.java` of my Android application
is throwing the `java.lang.AssertionError`. I have studied the problem again, then learned that the response of the API that is implemented on my website is being read by my Android application as null, thus with the aforementioned error.

I have also tried to solve the problem by doing the following:

1. Created a separate response class called ForgotPassRP with the same variables,   because the DataRP response class is being used by other classes.
2. Updated the version of the retrofit that is implemented in my
   build.grade(:app) from 2.7.2 to 2.9.0 and the retrofit2:converter-gson from 2.5.0  to 2.9.0.

Currently, I am still finding a solution by digging more about REST APIs on websites and Retrofit on Android, and I will implement anything new that I can learn from these. So am I missing something on my website, and Android code, or are there variables that are missing, while I am trying to do a POST method to the API that I have implemented to my website?

These are the following body of codes that I have analyzed so far that are connected to the problem (`java.lang.AssertionError`) that I am encountering on my Android application

The screenshot of the actual error that is being shown in the Logcat of my Android Studio:
[image: "java.lang.AssertionError` shown in the Logcat of my Android Studio]

**Website:**

**1. APIS.php**

```
 //This is where the @POST method from my Android application API interface of the "ForgotPassword.java" is communicating with
public function forgot_password_post()
    {

        $response = array();

        $user_info = $this->common_model->check_email($this->get_param['email'])[0];

        if (!empty($user_info)) 
        {

            $this->load->helper("rendomPassword");

            $info['new_password'] = get_random_password();

            $updateData = array(
                'user_password' => md5($info['new_password'])
            );

            $data_arr = array(
                'email' => $user_info->user_email,
                'password' => $info['new_password']
            );

            if ($this->common_model->update($updateData, $user_info->id, 'tbl_users')) {

                $subject = $this->app_name . ' - ' . $this->lang->line('forgot_password_lbl');

                $body = $this->load->view('admin/emails/forgot_password.php', $data_arr, TRUE);

                if (send_email($user_info->user_email, $user_info->user_name, $subject, $body)) 
                {
                    $row_info = array('success' => '1', 'msg' => $this->lang->line('password_sent_mail'));
                } 
                else 
                {
                    $row_info = array('success' => '0', $this->lang->line('email_not_sent'));
                }
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            $row_info = array('success' => '0', 'msg' => $this->lang->line('email_not_found'));
        }

        $this->set_response($row_info, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
    }
```

**Android Application**

**1. ForgotPassword.java**

```
package com.example.mototecxecommerceapp.activity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.mototecxecommerceapp.R;
import com.example.mototecxecommerceapp.response.DataRP;
import com.example.mototecxecommerceapp.response.ForgotPassRP;
import com.example.mototecxecommerceapp.rest.ApiClient;
import com.example.mototecxecommerceapp.rest.ApiInterface;
import com.example.mototecxecommerceapp.util.API;
import com.example.mototecxecommerceapp.util.ConstantApi;
import com.example.mototecxecommerceapp.util.Method;
import com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar;
import com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import io.github.inflationx.viewpump.ViewPumpContextWrapper;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class ForgetPassword extends AppCompatActivity {


    private Method method;
    private TextInputEditText editText;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    private InputMethodManager imm;

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(ViewPumpContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fp);

        method = new Method(ForgetPassword.this);
        method.forceRTLIfSupported();

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ForgetPassword.this);

        imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);

        MaterialToolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_fp);
        toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.forget_password));
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText_fp);
        MaterialButton button = findViewById(R.id.button_fp);

        button.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            String string_fp = editText.getText().toString();
            editText.setError(null);

            if (!isValidMail(string_fp) || string_fp.isEmpty()) {
                editText.requestFocus();
                editText.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.please_enter_email));
            } else {

                editText.clearFocus();
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);

                if (method.isNetworkAvailable()) {
                    forgetPassword(string_fp);
                } else {
                    method.alertBox(getResources().getString(R.string.internet_connection));
                }

            }

        });

    }

    private boolean isValidMail(String email) {
        return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
    }

    public void forgetPassword(String sendEmail) {

        progressDialog.show();
        progressDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.loading));
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

        JsonObject jsObj = (JsonObject) new Gson().toJsonTree(new API(ForgetPassword.this));
        jsObj.addProperty("email", sendEmail);

        ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<DataRP> call = apiService.getForgotPass(API.toBase64(jsObj.toString()));
        call.enqueue(new Callback<DataRP>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<DataRP> call, @NotNull Response<DataRP> response) {

                try {

                    DataRP dataRP = response.body();
                    assert dataRP != null; //This is the part of the code where the java.lang.AssertionError is being thrown.
           
                    if (dataRP.getStatus().equals("1")) {
                        if (dataRP.getSuccess().equals("1")) {
                            editText.setText("");
                        }
                        method.alertBox(dataRP.getMsg());
                    } else {
                        method.alertBox(dataRP.getMessage());
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d(ConstantApi.exceptionError, e.toString());
                    method.alertBox(getResources().getString(R.string.failed_response));
                }

                progressDialog.dismiss();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NotNull Call<DataRP> call, @NotNull Throwable t) {
                // Log error here since request failed
                Log.e(ConstantApi.failApi, t.toString());
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                method.alertBox(getResources().getString(R.string.failed_response));
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }

}
```

**2. ApiInterface.java**

```
//This is the post method that is being sent to the forgot password API of my website.
@POST("apis/forgot_password")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<DataRP> getForgotPass(@Field("data") String data);
```

**3. DataRP.java**

```
package com.example.mototecxecommerceapp.response;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.io.Serializable;

//This is the response from the @POST method.
public class DataRP implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("status")
    private String status;

    @SerializedName("message")
    private String message;

    @SerializedName("success")
    private String success;

    @SerializedName("msg")
    private String msg;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(String success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

}
```

I am also including the screenshot of the API logs that are being stored in the database that I have integrated into my website. This part is what seems to be the response of the "apis/forgot_password", whenever a post method that is thrown by my Android application is executed.

The SQL database of my website showing the logs related to "apis/forgotpassword"
[image: The SQL database of my website showing the logs related to "apis/forgotpassword"]

This is also my first time asking a question in StackOverflow. So please bear with any "rookie mistakes" with the format/structure of the question that I have posted :)

Comment: Whatever you do about calling the API correctly, you also have to fix your code so as to cope with the null value more elegantly than failing an assertion. Too broad.

Answer (score 0):

In the android application development most used Retrofit2 [Retrofit2 Documention](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-basics-of-api-description)

Then Generate Response Model Class (Call API using Postman). [Create a Response Model with JSON](https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Source type:> JSON. Annotation style:>Gson.

Use this code in the "onResponse" method section.

```
  if (response.isSuccessful()) {
     if (response.body() != null) {
         DataRP dataRp=response.body(); 
        //code statement... }  }
```